# How to copy all directories inside a directory from there to another directory using cp?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory structured like this,

```
/var/www/html/content/
|_dir1/
| |_somefile.txt
| |_anotherfile.js
| |_anotherfile.min.js
|
|_dir2/
  |_somefile.txt
  |_anotherfile.js
  |_anotherfile.min.js
```

I want to copy `dir1` and `dir2` to another directory. I have tried with the following command but it copies the entire `content` directory to the new location. I only need the directories inside `content` to be there.

```
cd ~/Desktop/new_location/
cp -r /var/www/html/content/. ./
```

**Update 2**

Both,

```
cp -r /var/www/html/content/. ./
```

and

```
cp -r /var/www/html/content/* ./
```

works fine. I have mistakenly included aonther `content` directory within the `content` directory making it `/var/www/html/content/content`

**Update 1**
Using the command posted by @Appleoddity in the first answer on a fresh directory works. But on the actual directory which I need to copy it fails. What could be the reason for this? Check the attached image.
[image: See it works on the new directory but not on the original]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cp -R /var/www/html/content/* /tmp/new_location/
```

`.` means “this” directory.
`*` means everything in “this” directory.

Comment: Tried it also. But still, it copies the `content` directory. I read on a StackOverflow answer that I should use the `.` but both are not working

Comment: @isuru-buddhika What do you mean it copies the `content` directory? This command will NOT create a `content` directory in the destination. It should copy the entire contents of the `content` directory.

Comment: @isuru-buddhika make sure you are using capital R. Not sure if it makes a difference here.

Comment: Hmm. actually, when I tested with `*` on a new directory it works fine. Currently, I have my script set use the `*` at the end. But on my old directory, it directly copies the parent directory instead of the content inside. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika is the old directory a symlink?

Comment: No. it's a normal directory
`drwxrwxr-x  3 root  root     4096 Jan 30 18:05 umc-deployments/`

could this be a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is your linux distro ?  I use the ubuntu 16.04.3 and it works by:

`cp -r /var/www/html/content/* /tmp/new_location/`

`-r` and `-R` are the same results :)